# Android webview rendering nothing after "#" character

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have an android application and I need to show a webview with my custom website. My problem is that the webview renders nothing. After using the "Element inspector" I could see that any HTML was being displayed after the first "#". For example, if my web is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <style>
            html {
                color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My awesome title</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

the rendered HTML on the webview will be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <style>
            html {
                color: 
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can use `rgb` colors. But I want to know what is going on here. Another example to clarify my problem is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <style>
            html {
                color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My awesome #title</h1>
        <p>this won't be displayed</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

the rendered HTML on the webview will be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <style>
            html {
                color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My awesome </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Seems like something with webview settings are you using the native webview, AdvancedWebview might be helpful: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to replace # with %23.

This change to the webview was introduced with the Chrome 72 update on 30th of January.

This pull request seems to be the reason why webview is broken after #: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1297172.

Comment: a better approach I think is encode the HTML passed to the webview in base64, which will avoid future bugs, if you other special character is used

Comment: Iván's solution works best.
Notice that a simple replace of # with %23 will break links that use "#" as fragment locator. I've pasted some code below.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented Iván's solution, and it works perfectly:

```
import android.util.Base64

fun loadBase64EncodedHtml(webView: WebView, html: String) {
    val encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(html.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), Base64.NO_PADDING)
    webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64")
}
```

and use it with:

```
val myHtmlContent = "<p>Your HTML content with special characters like #, but don't touch <a href="http://somewhere.com#fragment2"> .</p>"
loadBase64EncodedHtml(yourWebViewInstance, myHtmlContent)
```